# Picture Book for Learning Mishna berura

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, mishnah-berurah

Does anyone know of a good sefer that has pictures to learn in conjunction with mishna berura?

Comment: It really depends on the subject. There are some areas that are more technical and illustrations exist to help make the topic clearer, but then, there are some that are pretty straightforward and no visual aid is required.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sefer called Pe'er Halacha on hilchos tzitzits and teffilin . I believe they also made one for the daled minim. Another option which includes pictures when necessary is the new English Mishna Brurah Ohr Olam.

Sample from Pe'er Halacha:

[image]

Sample of Ohr Olam:

[image]